# Simple graphical calculator in ASP.NET MVC like MS Windows Calculator

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem in ASP.NET MVC to get expression when I click the `btnOne` -> `btn0` -> `btnPlus` -> `btn2` -> `btn1`. I want to have this expression: `10+21` and after click in `btnEqual` I want to get sum of this expression and get only one value in `textBox31` like in simple windows calculator. How to do that?

I have View named `Calculate`:

```
<body>
<div id="CalculatorSpace">
    <form name="Calc">
        <input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox" value=""/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="btnSeven" id="btnSeven" value="7" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnEight" value="8" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnNine" value="9" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="DEL" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnClear" value="CLR" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnFour" value="4" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnFive" value="5" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnSix" value="6" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnMultiply" value="*" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnDivide" value="/" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnOne" value="1" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnTwo" value="2" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnThree" value="3" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnPlus" value="+" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnMinus" value="-" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnZero" value="0" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnDot" value="." /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnEqual" value="=" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('btnSeven').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnSeven').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnEight').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnEight').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnNine').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnNine').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnDelete').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnDelete').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnClear').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnClear').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnFour').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnFour').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnFive').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnFive').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnSix').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnSix').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnMultiply').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnMultiply').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnDivide').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnDivide').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnOne').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnOne').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnTwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnTwo').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnThree').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnThree').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnPlus').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnPlus').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnMinus').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnMinus').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnZero').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnZero').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnDot').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnDot').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnEqual').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnEqual').value;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have CalculatorController look like this:

```
    public class CalculatorController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Calculator/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //GET: /Calculator/Calculate
    public ActionResult Calculate(string value)
    {

        return View();
    }

}
```

How do now to be entered in the expression `x + x` when you click `btnEqual` carries out the calculation of data (compared to pressed the +, -, *, /)?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Something like - http://csharpeval.codeplex.com/ - Might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Import [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) in to your project, then pass `textBox` to the controller and return the result of the `Expression`.

```
public ActionResult Calculate(String textBox)
{
    Expression e = new Expression(textBox);
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel {
        Answer = e.Evaluate()
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Or something of the sort...

Comment: What must be in the MyViewModel? I don't have any Model in Models catalogue. Second problem is how to import NCalc to my project and do I have to import all files of NCalc or only Expression class?